# What is the difference between Endoproteinase Lys-C and Lysyl endopeptidase?

Tags: terminology, biotechnology

What is the difference between [Endoproteinase Lys-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoproteinase_Lys-C) and [Lysyl endopeptidase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysyl_endopeptidase)?

In the text I'm translating about peptide mapping, "lysine protease" is mentioned (in Russian: лизиновая протеаза). This might be erroneous to translate word for word as "lysine protease". There must be a slight error in the original text. This "lysine protease" is mentioned there due to its use in protein hydrolysis.

I guess that the correct translation might be either **endoproteinase Lys-C** or **lysyl endopeptidase**.

I found that endoproteinase Lys-C is used in peptide mapping. Is it synonymous and interchangeable with lysyl endopeptidase, or do they differ in their function? Is endoproteinase Lys-C used more often as a hydrolysis agent in peptide mapping?

Maybe the difference is that endoproteinase Lys-C cleaves "on the C-terminal side of lysine residues", while lysyl endopeptidase cleaves on both sides?